# Ajax and php upload won't move image to upload folder

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Title says it all. When i upload file my code returns the name of the file but not it won't move the image to upload folder.Name of the image works fine so i am not really sure why the file won't go to it's proper destination.

```
index.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
/* Script written by Adam Khoury @ DevelopPHP.com */
/* Video Tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EraNFJiY0Eg */
function _(el){
    return document.getElementById(el);
}
function uploadFile(){
    var file = _("file1").files[0];
    //alert(file.name+" | "+file.size+" | "+file.type);
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("file1", file);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
    ajax.open("POST", "exp.php");
    ajax.send(formdata);
}
function progressHandler(event){
    _("loaded_n_total").innerHTML = "Uploaded "+event.loaded+" bytes of "+event.total;
    var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
    _("progressBar").value = Math.round(percent);
    _("status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent)+"% uploaded... please wait";
}
function completeHandler(event){
    _("status").innerHTML = event.target.responseText;
    _("progressBar").value = 0;
}
function errorHandler(event){
    _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Failed";
}
function abortHandler(event){
    _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Aborted";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTML5 File Upload Progress Bar Tutorial</h2>
<form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1"><br>
  <input type="button" value="Upload File" onclick="uploadFile()">
  <progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:300px;"></progress>
  <h3 id="status"></h3>
  <p id="loaded_n_total"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>

exp.php
 <?php

    $fileName = $_FILES["file1"]["name"]; // The file name
    $fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"]; // File in the PHP tmp folder
    $fileType = $_FILES["file1"]["type"]; // The type of file it is
    $fileSize = $_FILES["file1"]["size"]; // File size in bytes
    $fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["file1"]["error"]; // 0 for false... and 1 for true
    if (!$fileTmpLoc) { // if file not chosen
        echo "ERROR: Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button.";
        exit();
    }
    if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "uploads/")){
        echo "$fileName upload is complete
        <img src='uploads/$fileName' width='100' height='100'>
        ";
    } else {
        echo "move_uploaded_file function failed";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: I don't think your JS is doing the trick.  You probably need to stop the form from submitting.  Also, file uploads don't like AJAX http://www.ajaxf1.com/tutorial/ajax-file-upload-tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

You missed the file name in the target.
Replace `move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "uploads/")` by `move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "dir/to/uploads/".$fileName)`

Comment: it isn't working same result ... :(

Comment: Why don't you have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp to just cross check your code :)

Comment: i did and it ain't working again...try code yourself and if u fix it i'll buy you a chocolate :D

Comment: Nothing in error log? Maybe a permissions problem moving the file....

Comment: After "uploads/" change "+" on "." and it will be working

Comment: @Dmitriy.Net got mixed up between Java and PHP. Thanks :)